# BytesIO, открыть изображение в cv2.imread( предварительно не сохраняя его

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
im = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(im, format="png", dpi=DPI)
im.seek(0)
```

Не сохраняю, затем открываю

```
img = Image.open(im)
```

Работает, другой вопрос как выполнить тоже самое но открыть его в

```
cv2.imread(im)
```

В данном случаи ошибка

```
 img_rgb = cv2.imread(im)
SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

**Решение**

```
cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(im.getvalue(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Но не цвет бордюров границ вхождения изменились

```
# Читать основное изображение
#img_rgb = cv2.imread(f'{patch}1111.png')
img_rgb = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(im.getvalue(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
# Прочитайте шаблон
template = cv2.imread(f'{patch}6-spectrogram/22222.png',0)
# Сохраняем ширину и высоту шаблона в ш и ч
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
# Преобразовать его в оттенки серого/ Выполнять операции сопоставления.
res = cv2.matchTemplate(cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
# Сохранять координаты совпадающей области в массиве
loc = np.where( res >= 0.8) 
# Нарисуйте прямоугольник вокруг соответствующей области.
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)
#Сохраняем изображение
cv2.imwrite(f'{patch}finish.png', img_rgb)
```

[image: Загружаем изображение]

[image: Предварительно не сохраняем, верней сохраняем уже в переменную цвет бордюров изменился]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте через `numpy`, используя `frombuffer` получить массив, а после его преобразовать через `cv2.imdecode`:

```
nparr = np.frombuffer(im.getvalue(), np.uint8)
img_rgb = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: Работает но есть одно но это выходное изображение где областью, выделен прямоугольником желтого цвета (https://ibb.co/nnwWNPQ). Это результат того, если изображение предварительно сохранять. А этот результат (https://ibb.co/mvD8KnG) выполнен без  предварительного сохранения. Но возможно разглядеть границы(бордюры) того же прямоугольника. Только цвет бордюров изменился под фон. С чем это связанно?

Comment: В посте первом, добавил тот код который собственно ищет вхождения

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, мб в той рамке прозрачность используется... Попробуйте `im.getvalue()` сохранить в файл: `open('img.png', 'wb').write(im.getvalue())` и проверьте наличие рамки. Если ее нет, значит проблема уже была при `plt.savefig(im, format="png", dpi=DPI)`. Если рамка есть, значит нужно поиграться с параметрами `np.frombuffer` или `cv2.imdecode`